# Getting a 500 request error on a particular API endpoint in Jersey?

Tags: java, maven, jersey

I am currently implementing a API through Jersey. In the below code I have a class with a GET operation which returns a float. When I call this method I am getting the below error message :

```
MessageBodyWriter not found for media type=application/json, type=class 
java.lang.Float, genericType=float.
```

Now I have googled around and the general consensus is that either I do not have a default constructor on my model class, I don't have the correct dependency (notably the : org.glassfish.jersey.media) or I don't have the correct annotation on my class. I have all these however.

Strangely, all of my other end points are working as expected in the same class, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Model Class

  @XmlRootElement
  public class Product {

    private float pprice;

    public Project(){}

    public Project(float pprice)
    {
        this.pprice = pprice;
    }
    // relevant getter and setters
  }
```

Endpoint class

```
    @Path("/product")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public class ProductS {

    @GET
    @Path("/products/{productID}")
    public float getAccountBalance(@PathParam("productID") int productID){
        float b =  ps.getb(productID);
        return b;
    }

}
```

Note, the rest of my endpoints work as expected, just this call pops that error

Comment: Have you tried with.'Float'?

Comment: Have a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26207252/messagebodywriter-not-found-for-media-type-application-json